# IDA code snippet, eax moved into global variable

Tags: assembly, ida

Doing exercises from the book *Pratical Malware Analysis* (Lab 5-1)

The global variable `dword_1008E5C4` (2nd picture) is supposed to contain the OS version, but from what I can see it should always be set to 0 because of the 
`xor eax, eax` instruction in `sub_10003695`

Am I missing something?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, you are missing something.  EAX doesn't contain the version.  The LEA loads the address of where that data is.  When EAX is cleared, it is just clearing it as a return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`GetVersionEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx) function has this signature:

```
BOOL WINAPI GetVersionEx(
  _Inout_ LPOSVERSIONINFO lpVersionInfo
);
```

So it returns a [`OSVERSIONINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724834(v=vs.85).aspx) structure (or `OSVERSIONINFOEX`, but that's not relevant here) in a local variable on the stack (here referenced rel to `EBP`) which field `dwPlatformId` is checked with the

```
cmp [ebp+VersionInformation.dwPlatformId], 2
```

instruction. A value of `2` does indicate

> The operating system is Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, or Windows 2000.

so on those systems the `CMP` sets the `ZERO?` flag indicating equality. Because the `ZERO?` flag is now set and `EAX` is still zero

```
setz al
```

sets `EAX` to `00000001` - being the *return value* of the subroutine.

Comment: Ohh, thanks, now I (mostly) understand. Forgot al was part of eax :)
So the call to GetVersionExA fills [ebp+VersionInformation] with the struct. Guess I'm a bit confused about how the callee function changes the value of a local variable of the caller

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `setz` instruction, which sets the value of `al` (part of `eax`) based on the result of the comparison above it.